# Distinct select from Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following code to select the names of staff from a `Core Data` entity called StaffRecords. I want to select the records `Distinctly` but this selects all the records. How do I make the result `Distinct`?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"StaffRecords"];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"StaffName"]];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
NSError *error = nil;
self.StaffNames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `setPropertiesToFetch` and `setReturnsDistinctResults` is correct. But, you also need to set `resultType` to `NSDictionaryResultType`.

Note that at the time of writing `propertiesToFetch` is documented to be an array of `NSPropertyDescription` instances, but an array of strings of the key names does also work.

Comment: The first part is not correct. `propertiesToFetch` can take an array of NSStrings with the property *names*.

Comment: Thanks. I have set resultType to NSDictionaryResultType and I can tell that it is working as NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self. StaffNames count]); shows I have correct number. I now have a different problem accessing the NSDictionary ... new to these. Another question perhaps. Thanks again.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks, I couldn't remember exactly and a quick check of the docs didn't say. Is it actually documented somewhere (or just the 'The name of an attribute ...' part)?

Comment: @Wain: I am quite sure that is was documented as "An array of NSPropertyDescription or NSExpressionDescription objects, or keypath strings" when I looked it up some time ago, similar to `setPropertiesToGroupBy:`. - But the current documentation does not state it explicitly, so either I am mistaken or the documentation has changed. But I have used it that way and it worked.